# Woocommerce hide category tag from single product page - 14.09.2022

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Question: Hide Category Tag shown on the Product Single Page

Help: hide category from single product page

Woocommerce release: Version 6.8.2

With the new woocommerce update, now I have the “ Category Tag ” shown on the single product page. The point is, I already have three times the snippet below inserted in my function.php file.

This snippet made a good Job before some update to be released in the world.

```
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
```

I do not known exactly with which update this function,filter was disabled. Now I have my single product page design totally broken.

I have the following filter already tested, but this filter hide only the Category Tag from the Shop Page. That´s is his task.

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'ts_get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );

function ts_get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {

    $new_terms = array();

    // if it is a product category and on the shop page

    if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() &&is_shop() ) {

        foreach( $terms as $key => $term ) {

            if ( !in_array( $term->slug, array( 'uncategorized') ) ) { //pass the slug name here

                $new_terms[] = $term;

            }
        }

        $terms = $new_terms;

    }

    return $terms;
}
```

Does someone also experienced this situation that could give a little help?

I am looking for answer alreay by Google and the documentation for the last 6 hours.

Here is the broken page with the category tags - Screenshot

Thank you advance!

[image: This is the broken page with the category tags]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution, but only in the Admin Visual Area.

**In Apperance -> Personalize -> Woocommerce -> Individual Product -> General -> Single Product Structure**

I disabled the Tags that I do not use in my **Single Product Page** and the design cameback to my reality

[image: My Correction accordance my necessity]